# RPi Share visible yet invisible on Windows Network

Tags: windows, samba

I have 3 RPi B's with V2 cameras attached to a windows domain network (Server 2012 R2). All of the RPi's are visible on the network by name (RPi1, RPi2, RPi3) and can be connected by RDP from the Windows 7 computers and the Server. Each of the RPi's has a shared folder. JPGs  from these shared folders will be processed into time lapse movies by a PC.

Although the 3 RPi's are visible on every Win7 computer, only one RPi's share can be accessed by two of the Windows 7 computers. The other computers can access the shares on all three RPi's. I've tried editing the SMB.conf on the 2 invisible pi's and have gone so far as to copy the smb.conf from the visible one to the others to no avail.

The only way I have been able to get all the shares visible on the 2 recalcitrant Win 7 computers is to type the full path to the share in the dialog box in the START menu of the two Win 7 computers. The names of the RPi's have been set up in Raspi-config, and those names are visible on all the PC's

This is a subtle problem that has been driving me crazy! Any ideas? Incidentally the software on the 3 RPi's is the same.

Comment: sounds like a Microsoft Windows problem

Comment: @jsotola Excluding the RPi makes the problem go away, so you might as well call it an RPi problem :)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev `Excluding the RPi makes the problem go away` - Probably missing something here, but how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, `Excluding the RPi makes the problem go away` .... i do not see that information in the post text

Comment: So just to add some more detail..The error message from a Win 7 Pro PC is "\\RPI3 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource, etc., Then the message continues..."The username could not be found". But entering \\10.0.2.xx\share works, asks for RPi password and connects.

Comment: @jostola The basic rule of thumb is: if you exclude the RPi or replace it by a "Linux PC" and the question is unchanged, then it's off-topic. If you exclude the RPi from this question, there's no problem any longer since there's no share that the OP cannot access by name. So I don't agree it's off-topic.